# Org auto numbering of list with <RET>

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Lets say I have the following *Org* file:

```
Bla bla bla
1. BlaX
```

And let's say my cursor is where "X" is, and I am in insert mode (I use Evil mode in Emacs). Now, if I press <kbd>M-RET</kbd> I will get auto numbers in a list like this:

```
Bla bla bla
1. BlaX
2.
```

My question is, how can I make it happen with just <kbd>RET</kbd> and not <kbd>M-RET</kbd>?

1. It just seems more natural to me and a more sane default.
2. I am constantly forgetting to do <kbd>M-RET</kbd> and do a <kbd>RET</kbd> and wonder why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach, I think, would be to check to which function <kbd>M-RET</kbd> is bound, and then bind <kbd>RET</kbd> to it instead. For instance, if <kbd>C-h c</kbd> <kbd>M-RET</kbd> outputs "org-meta-return", then use this configuration:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'org-meta-return)
```

But the full story may be a bit more complex than that, so there's a chance you'd need more settings tweaked. This is a case because `org-mode` has quite a lot of configurational "sugar" added. To handle that, read a bound function's documentation carefully for every confusing keybinding.

One bright example: <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-return-and-maybe-indent` reveals indentation behavior can have many influencers. Namely,

> When inserting a newline, if ‘org-adapt-indentation’ is t: indent the
> line if ‘electric-indent-mode’ is disabled, don’t indent it if it is
> enabled.

A small [cheatsheet](https://github.com/yugaego/emacs-config/blob/173bf8eb994b5c3850bbc5e73c75db7f71df86e4/configs/init-org.el#L45) of mine might help figuring that out.